# I got some R / Oceanographic problems...how to compare two columns of different length and digits

Tags: r, loops, comparison

I have a little situation that I cant solve, I got a several lengthy datasets with several columns, the subset of two data.frames would look like this:

```
Temp <- c(12.9423 ,12.9446 ,12.9412 ,12.9617 ,12.9742 ,12.9652 ,12.9463, 12.9847 ,12.9778,
        12.9589, 12.9305, 12.9275 ,12.8569 ,12.8531 ,12.9092, 12.9471, 12.9298, 12.9266,
        12.9374 ,12.9385, 12.9505, 12.9510, 12.9632 ,12.9621 ,12.9571, 12.9492 ,12.8988,
        12.8895 ,12.8777, 12.8956, 12.8748 ,12.7850 ,12.7323, 12.7546 ,12.7375 ,12.7020,
        12.7172, 12.7015, 12.6960, 12.6944, 12.6963, 12.6928, 12.6930 ,12.6883 ,12.6913)

Density <- c(26.38635 ,26.38531 ,26.38429, 26.38336, 26.38268 ,26.38242, 26.38265, 26.38343,
           26.38486, 26.38697 ,26.38945, 26.39188, 26.39365, 26.39424 ,26.39376 ,26.39250,
           26.39084 ,26.38912 ,26.38744 ,26.38587, 26.38456 ,26.38367, 26.38341 ,26.38398,
           26.38547 ,26.38793 ,26.39120 ,26.39509, 26.39955 ,26.40455, 26.41002, 26.41578,
           26.42126, 26.42593 ,26.42968, 26.43255 ,26.43463, 26.43603 ,26.43693 ,26.43750,
           26.43787, 26.43815, 26.43841 ,26.43871 ,26.43904)

po4 <-  c(0.4239840 ,0.4351156, 0.4456128, 0.4542392, 0.4608510, 0.4656445, 0.4690847,
        0.4717291, 0.4742391 ,0.4774904 ,0.4831152, 0.4922122, 0.5029904, 0.5128720,
        0.5190209, 0.5191368 ,0.5133212, 0.5027542 ,0.4905301 ,0.4796467 ,0.4708035,
        0.4638879, 0.4578364 ,0.4519745, 0.4481336, 0.4483697, 0.4531310, 0.4622930,
        0.4750474 ,0.4905152 ,0.5082183 ,0.5278212 ,0.5491580 ,0.5720519, 0.5961127,
        0.6207716 ,0.6449603, 0.6675704 ,0.6878331 ,0.7051851,0.7195461, 0.7305200,
        0.7359634 ,0.7343541, 0.7283988)

PP14 <- data.frame(Temp,Density,po4) ##df1

temp <- c(13.13875, 13.13477 ,13.12337 ,13.10662 ,13.09798 ,13.09542 ,13.08734 ,13.07616,
 13.06671 ,13.05899, 13.05890 ,13.05293 ,13.03322, 13.01515, 13.02552 ,13.01668,
12.99829, 12.97075 ,12.95572 ,12.95045 ,12.94541 ,12.94365 ,12.94609 ,12.94256,
12.93565 ,12.93258 ,12.93489 ,12.93209 ,12.92219 ,12.90730 ,12.90416 ,12.89974,
 12.89749 ,12.89626 ,12.89395, 12.89315 ,12.89274, 12.89276 ,12.89293 ,12.89302)

density <- c( 26.35897, 26.36274 ,26.36173 ,26.36401 ,26.36507 ,26.36662 ,26.36838,
26.36996,
  26.37286 ,26.37452 ,26.37402, 26.37571 ,26.37776, 26.38008 ,26.37959 ,26.38178,
26.38642 ,26.39158 ,26.39350, 26.39467, 26.39601, 26.39601, 26.39596 ,26.39517,
26.39728 ,26.39766, 26.39774, 26.39699 ,26.40081 ,26.40328 ,26.40416, 26.40486,
26.40513 ,26.40474 ,26.40552 ,26.40584, 26.40613, 26.40602 ,26.40595 ,26.40498)

krho <- c( -9.999999e+06, -1.786843e+00, -9.142976e-01, -9.650734e-01, -2.532397e+00,
  -3.760537e+00, -2.622484e+00, -1.776506e+00, -2.028391e+00, -2.225910e+00,
  -3.486826e+00, -2.062341e-01, -3.010643e+00, -3.878437e+00, -3.796426e+00,
-3.227138e+00, -3.335446e+00, -3.738037e+00, -4.577778e+00, -3.818099e+00,
-3.891467e+00, -4.585045e+00 ,-3.150283e+00 ,-4.371089e+00 ,-3.902601e+00,
-4.546019e+00, -3.932538e+00, -4.331247e+00, -4.508137e+00, -4.789201e+00,
   -4.383820e+00, -4.423486e+00, -4.334641e+00, -4.330544e+00, -4.838604e+00,
    -4.729123e+00, -4.381797e+00, -4.207365e+00, -4.276804e+00, -4.001305e+00)

MS14 <- data.frame(temp,density,krho) ##df2
```

I need to refer or compare the density +- 0.01 of MS14 to the density +- 0.01 of PP14, to get the values of the other columns that are related to that particular density.However if I use == would never be the same because all have 5 digits and none of the values would be the same...

To solve that I though it would make sense to compare both densities MS14$density and  PP14$Density, +-0.01 whenever the similarity is true that value of that raw should be store together with all the other values of that row for all the columns in MS14 but also in PP14, so that at the end we get a df3 that would have all the columns because thereafter I need to do F= -krho * dPO4/dz so I need to keep the values "sorted by density"...

Any ideas and suggestions?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you expect to have 45 Rows in df3 ? Because given the small variations in the density values, a match on density +-0.01 means that for a given row, many rows will correspond based on this single criterion.

Comment: No need to get 45 rows in df3, just all the densities that match with each other...I know that is part of the challenge, perhaps I could add the column Depth in PP14 but I dont have a depth in MS14 therefore the goal is to sort MS14 using as reference the density in PP14... How to find the commons I figured...but how to paste all the rows with columns in df3???

Comment: i added to my answer but my way is more complicated than @FrancoisL11 so i suggest using his answer

Comment: @D.J, thanks yes, I just saw it..I guess we are in a different time zone =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so based on your reply: "No need to get 45 rows in df3, just all the densities that match with each other."
I think you could try this out:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df3 <- difference_left_join(PP14, MS14, 
                            by = c("Density"="density"), max_dist = 0.01) %>%
  arrange(density)
df3 %>% head()

     Temp  Density       po4     temp  density      krho
1 12.9742 26.38268 0.4608510 13.06671 26.37286 -2.028391
2 12.9652 26.38242 0.4656445 13.06671 26.37286 -2.028391
3 12.9463 26.38265 0.4690847 13.06671 26.37286 -2.028391
4 12.9617 26.38336 0.4542392 13.05890 26.37402 -3.486826
5 12.9742 26.38268 0.4608510 13.05890 26.37402 -3.486826
6 12.9652 26.38242 0.4656445 13.05890 26.37402 -3.486826
```

Comment: thanks so much...seems to work even though it repeats several values its fine but when I try it on my real data set it says 
Error: Names repair functions can't return `NA` values.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Are you familiar with that error? I guess could be not all the columns are vectors there are also chr...

Comment: Can you give the column names of your datasets?

Comment: > names(pp14)
 [1] "Station"        "Depth"          "Temp"           "Salinity"      
 [5] "Fluoresc"       "Density"        "Oxygen"         "Nitrate "      
 [9] "Ammonia"        "Phosphate"      "Nitrite"        "Silicate"      
[13] "Oxygen2"        "Nitrate"        "Density_round"  "Density_round2"

Comment: names(MSS14)
 "sday"  "slat"  "slon" "X.press" "temp"          "cond"          "turb"          "p250" "psal"     "asal"  "ptemp" "ctemp" "sigma0"  "rho" "bvf2" "thorpe_sc" "thorpe_dis"    "sigma0_sort"   "oxy_s" "oxy_c" "epsilon"       "peps"          "krho" "Re_b"         
"L_oz"  "krho_s"        "sacw"          "wm_ox"        
 "aou"           "Tu_ang"        "R_rho"         "sigma0_round" 
"sigma0_round2"



I removed the chr columns, the error says : 
Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
x Could not create a temporary column for `..1`.
ℹ `..1` is `density`.

Comment: Mmh I'm not sure andit is a  bit difficult to treat the problem like this. From what I have seen, Error with name repairs arise from incorrect column names. For instance, you may import a csv file with non-unique column names. R will read the file into a data.frame but if you try to modify the data.frame you will need to fix the names or you will get an error. 
So you could try to import your data giving a vector of correct, unique names with your read function.

Comment: thanks a lot it works perfectly...it was just a typo ><, thanks again your input was life saver hehe !O-o

Answer (score 0):

well, one problem you have is that the columns have different lengths.

but assuming you cut them to the same length maybe this would help:

```
library(tidyverse)

similar<-dplyr::near(MS14$density, PP14$Density, tol=0.01) ##PP14 has 45 columns while MS14 has only 40

MS14$similar<-similar
PP14$similar<-similar
MS14[MS14$similar==T,]
PP14[PP14$similar==T,]

df3<-na.omit(cbind.data.frame(MS14[MS14$similar==T,], PP14[PP14$similar==T,]))


       temp  density      krho similar    Temp  Density       po4 similar
17 12.99829 26.38642 -3.335446    TRUE 12.9298 26.39084 0.5133212    TRUE
18 12.97075 26.39158 -3.738037    TRUE 12.9266 26.38912 0.5027542    TRUE
19 12.95572 26.39350 -4.577778    TRUE 12.9374 26.38744 0.4905301    TRUE
20 12.95045 26.39467 -3.818099    TRUE 12.9385 26.38587 0.4796467    TRUE
26 12.93258 26.39766 -4.546019    TRUE 12.9492 26.38793 0.4483697    TRUE
27 12.93489 26.39774 -3.932538    TRUE 12.8988 26.39120 0.4531310    TRUE
28 12.93209 26.39699 -4.331247    TRUE 12.8895 26.39509 0.4622930    TRUE
29 12.92219 26.40081 -4.508137    TRUE 12.8777 26.39955 0.4750474    TRUE
30 12.90730 26.40328 -4.789201    TRUE 12.8956 26.40455 0.4905152    TRUE
31 12.90416 26.40416 -4.383820    TRUE 12.8748 26.41002 0.5082183    TRUE
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't cut the lengths, because I would loose too much information. I could either fill with NA or interpolate maybe...
Once there, how to paste the files all together that are true?

Comment: thank you @D.J , I like the way the data.frames are structured  without repetition of numbers, but the different length are still a problem. I wonder how to fill NANs..it might be easier than interpolate MS14 <- data.frame(approx(MS14$density, n=45,))

Comment: But then I can only interpolate 2 columns x and y..so its not the best way...missing information again of the other columns... if you know a line that will just ad NAN rows to fill it until nrow(PP14) which is 45...that could be great...

Comment: you can repeat this in a loop so you can do i for as many columns as you like although i am sure some vectorized operation is even better. i don't know if you can set NA to NaN... but you can do this to create the correct amounts of NA: `a<-data.frame(matrix(, nrow=PP14[,1], ncol=length(MS14)))
names(a)<-names(MS14)
MS14 <- rbind(MS14, a)`